# How to add header to get request in vue js?

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuex

I am taking data from api, how to send get request with token after login?

It shows error `createError.js?2d83:16 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 401`

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    users: []
  },
  mutations: {
    setUsers(state, args){
      state.users = args;
    }
  },
  actions: {
    login({ }, arg) {
      axios.post('login/', { username: arg.username, password: arg.password })

        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response);
          let accessToken = response.token.data;
          localStorage.setItem('token', accessToken);
          localStorage.setItem('user', response.data.user);
          axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = accessToken;
          window.isSignedIn = true;
          router.push('/');
        })

        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        })
    },
    getUsers({ commit }){
      let { data } = axios.get('v1/user/list/');
      commit('setUsers', data);
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Depends which authentication you are using. Try with:
`` axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${accessToken}`; ``

Other [HTTP authentication schemes](http://www.iana.org/assignments/http-authschemes/http-authschemes.xhtml).